# How to set profile image center of the line

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to set rounded profile image center of the line . How can i do it.
  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkbEV.png)

Comment: What did you try so far...

Comment: @Stheesh, it\`s not a place "I have an idea, tell me how I should do". It\`s "I have a trouble with this code -> `some code`, I did looking up a solution and trying some ways... help me pls"

Comment: @satheesh: Welcome to stackoverflow :)... I think you should read this before you post https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Just try to make a round image and shape it using **borderRadius** in your style and then render it on top of some other object like the line you saying. [Try to check this link](https://reactnativecode.com/show-round-shape-image-component/)
I hope this would help you.